# JSoup query: how to find all instances of an HTML tag in another tag

Tags: html, jsoup

I have an HTML page to scan for headings and figure elements. The code of the HTML file is:

```html
    <body>
    <section>
        <h2>H2-1</h2>
        <div>
            <section>
                <h3>H3-1</h3>
                <div>
                    <figure><img src="Fig 1.png"></figure>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h3>H3-2</h3>
                <div></div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>H2-2</h2>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="Fig 2.png"></figure>
            <figure><img src="Fig 3.png"></figure>
            <figure><img src="Fig 4.png"></figure>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>H2-3</h2>
        <div>
            <figure><img src="Fig 5.png"></figure>
            <section>
                <h3>H3-3</h3>
                <div><figure><img src="Fig 6.png"></figure></div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>H2-4</h2>
        <div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </body>
```

The output I want is:

```
H2-1
  H3-1
    Fig 1
H2-2
  Fig 2
  Fig 3
  Fig 4
H2-3
  Fig 5
  H3-3
    Fig 6
```

I want to find show all headings that has a child figure element.  I do not want to display the heading if it does to have an immediate child figure element.

The JSoup code I am trying is:

```java
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sourceCode);
    Elements sectionTags = doc.body().getElementsByTag("section");
    for (Element sectTag : sectionTags)
    {
      System.out.println (sectTag.children().first().ownText());  //print the Heading text 
      Elements figureTags = sectTag.getElementsByTag("figure");
      for (Element figTag : figureTags) 
      {
        System.out.println (figTag.getElementsByTag("img").attr("src").toString());  // print the image name
      }                          
    }
```

but I am not getting the desired output. The output that I get is:

```
H2-1
  Fig 1
  H3-1
    Fig 1
H2-2
  Fig 2
H2-3
  Fig 5
  H3-3
    Fig 6
```

Any help? I am new to JSoup and appreciate any suggestion or tip that can work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code here please?

Comment: I posted the html code and the JSoup code I tried in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
/*function to parse the HTML*/
private void parseHTML(String szHTML){
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(szHTML);

    Elements arrEle = doc.select("section");

    for(Element child: arrEle){
        printSectionDetails(child);
    }
}

/*function to print section details : prints direct child header name and img src of the section node */
private void printSectionDetails(Element section){
    Elements arrChildren = section.children();
    for(Element child : arrChildren){
        if(isHeader(child.tagName())){
            System.out.println(child.text());
        }

        if(child.tagName().equals("div")){
            Elements children = child.children();

            for(Element grandchild : children){
                if(grandchild.tagName().equals("figure")){
                    Elements arrImgs = grandchild.select("img");
                    for(Element img : arrImgs){
                        System.out.println(img.attr("src"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/*checks whether the tag is a header*/
private boolean isHeader(String tagName) {
    if("h1".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName) || "h2".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName) || "h3".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName) || "h4".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName) || "h5".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName) || "h1".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName) || "h6".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, kind of. Sorry for replying late.Based on your script, I made some modifications and it is working, so far. Many thanks for your expert help.